# Building two different versions a given war with maven profiles and filtering from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, continuous-integration, cloud-foundry

I am trying to use **maven profiles** and **filtering** in order to produce **two different versions** of a given web archive (**war**):

1. A first one for **local deployment** to my local machine on localhost
2. A second one for **remote deployment** to cloudfoundry

There are a number of properties that differ according to whether the app is deployed to my local machine or to cloudfoundry.

Of course the difficult bit is that **I am trying to do all this from STS/Eclipse** and deploy from Eclipse to my local tomcat and to cloudfoundry...

Can anyone please provide advice, tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Spring versioning 3.1+ the "profile" attribute for `<beans>` in the spring bean configuration xml would be the best choice. Take a look at the doc here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html#using-spring-profiles-to-conditionalize-cloud-foundry-configuration

Basically you need to specify at least 2  elements. One for your local properties (`profile="default"`) and one for the properties when deployed to CF. The latter one should be defined as `<beans profile="cloud">`. When running locally the properties within "cloud" would be ignored and properties in "default" will take effect. When pushed to CF, CF will detect the profile named "cloud" and, which is better, inject corresponding datasource connection info of the services provisioned by CF itself. You can find the detailed CF-specified properties in that doc as well.

For more information about the profile attribute, see the doc here: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Comment: Hi William and thanks very much for your input! I have one more interrogation regarding spring profiles: say I have the following property: `kadjoukor.websiteContext=http://localhost:8080/kadjoukor` in a properties file and possibly another production/cloud value for that property. I use the @Value annotation in order to use this property. How can spring profile help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a single project per artifact generated.  Hence one project generating your local deployment and one project generating your cloudfoundry deployment.

Overlays (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) is the officially sanctioned way to bake in extra files in an existing WAR file, giving a new WAR artifact.  Very useful but may be too slow for comfort while developing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Thorbjorn!! I was not aware of this maven feature... I am having trouble deploying the overlay to Eclipse's tomcat but this is a different issue so I will open another thread.

Comment: One more question though: can I deploy war overlays to cloudfoundry?

Comment: The output of this is still a war. Check the contents carefully